# ¿Cuál es el correcto uso de "los que" y "cuyos"?

Tags: gramática

Me he encontrado con un ejercicio de español en el cual se tiene que escoger entre 3 opciones: `que`, `los que` y `cuyos`. ¿Cuál es la opcion correcta y por qué? El enunciado es el siguiente:

> Un agente es quien se encarga de encontrar editorial para los libros de los escritores a _______ representa: quien negocia y ...

De las tres opciones, las que tengo en mente son `los que` y `cuyos`. La opción correcta creo que es `cuyos`, pero no soy capaz de explicar el porqué.

Answer (score 2):

Como se puede comprobar en el DLE, la palabra *[cuyo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Bnkxw0N)* es un adjetivo. Eso quiere decir que necesariamente deberá modificar a un sustantivo. Para usar la voz *cuyo* la frase debería estar estructurada así:

> ... encontrar editorial para los libros a cuyos autores representa...

De esta forma, el adjetivo *cuyos* modificaría a *autores*. Sin embargo, en el ejemplo dado después de la palabra a insertar va un verbo: *representar*. Luego podemos descartar *cuyo*, y nos pasamos a la otra opción: *[que](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UkbUarn)*. Esta voz constituye un pronombre relativo que introduce oraciones relativas y hace referencia a un antecedente expreso. En este caso el antecedente es *escritores*. La oración se podría presentar de dos formas:

> ... encontrar editorial para los libros de los escritores que representa...
>   ... encontrar editorial para los libros de los escritores a los que representa...

La segunda forma tiene la estructura de complemento preposicional, que necesita una preposición más un artículo (como en *jugar a los dados*). Dado que la oración de ejemplo deja claro que la preposición debe estar ahí, la única opción válida es la segunda:

> Un agente es quien se encarga de encontrar editorial para los libros de los escritores a `los que` representa: quien negocia y...

Comment: ¿En el primer ejemplo no sería _... encontrar editorial para los libros **a** cuyos autores representa..._?

Comment: @blonfu me acabas de pillar del todo. Me sonaba bien tal y como yo lo puse, pero ahora me entra la duda. Habrá que consultarlo.